# How to convert runtime parameter value into dependency within WebJobs function and Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-webjobs, simple-injector

I have a WebJobs function that has a method/trigger. One of its parameters corresponds to WebJobs dashboard logger:

```
public Task MyQueueHandler(TextWriter log)
```

How can I convert or register this `TextWriter log` in the container so could inject it into my another class's ctor:

```
public MyLogger(TextWriter log)
```

Is there a way like by using ExecutionContextScoping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract `TextWriter` behind a provider and inject the provider into the logger instead (since `TextWriter` is clearly runtime data, you should [prevent injecting it into your components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) directly). This allows you to set this value into the provider when MyQueueHandler is called. For instance:

```
// Definition
public interface ITextWriterProvider // by lack of a better name
{
    TextWriter Current { get; }
}

// Used as dependency of MyLogger
public MyLogger(ITextWriterProvider logProvider)

// Implementation visible to your composition root
public class TextWriterProvider : ITextWriterProvider
{
    public TextWriter Current { get; set; }
}

// Registration
container.Register<ITextWriterProvider, TextWriterProvider>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<TextWriterProvider>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

// Wrap the start of the request in a scope and assign the log value to the scope.
public Task MyQueueHandler(TextWriter log)
{
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
    {
        container.GetInstance<TextWriterProvider>().Current = log;

        // execute rest of request
    }
}
```

As a variation of this design you can also make the `TextWriterProvider` a singleton and make its value `AsyncLocal`, as follows:

```
public class TextWriterProvider : ITextWriterProvider
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<TextWriter> current =
        new AsyncLocal<TextWriter>();

    public TextWriter Current
    { 
        get => current.Value;
        set => current.Value = value;
    }
}

// Registration
container.Register<ITextWriterProvider, TextWriterProvider>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<TextWriterProvider>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Or even simpler:

```
public class TextWriterProvider : ITextWriterProvider
{
    public static readonly AsyncLocal<TextWriter> CurrentWriter =
        new AsyncLocal<TextWriter>();

    public TextWriter Current => CurrentWriter.Value;
}

// Registration
container.Register<ITextWriterProvider, TextWriterProvider>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

// Assign the log to the CurrentWriter at the start of the request
public Task MyQueueHandler(TextWriter log)
{
    TextWriterProvider.CurrentWriter = log;

    // execute rest of request
}
```

These are all variations of the same design where we extract the runtime data from the constructor and allow resolving it *after* the object graph has been constructed.

If that all fails, it is possible to inject this runtime value directly into the object graph. Note that I strongly advice against this, but see it as a last-resort option:

```
// Part of your Composition Root
public static AsyncLocal<TextWriter> Writer = new AsyncLocal<TextWriter>();

// Registration
container.Register<ILogger>(() => new MyLogger(
    Writer ?? (container.IsVerifying ? new TextWriter() : null)));

// Assign the log to the CurrentWriter at the start of the request
public Task MyQueueHandler(TextWriter log)
{
    CompositionRoot.CurrentWriter = log;

    // execute rest of request
}
```